# How to Flip ImageButton in Android programmatically

Tags: android, imagebutton, android-animation, flip

I am having 3 ImageButton in my application. I wish to add some nice flipping effect on them. What i want is if i click on one button then there are more button as there is total 3, so the other button should be flipped. If any one has seen the Talking Tom app then i want the exactly same thing in my app. Here are some snapshot of that Talking tom app...

.[image]   [image]

**See the two images. In the images you can see that on the right hand side at the bottom there is a button with icon of FLIP. On click of that, there is another button with TEA and SCRATCH icon on the left side at bottom. SO what happens when i click on the flip button the TEA & SCRATCH button are flip accordingly.**

I want to do the same thing..I found tutorials which are on View, Images and in that they used separate layout file for that. I think that's not the case in my app. If anyone has any idea about this please kindly let me know....

Thanks

Comment: or.. programatically just change the image.. of the imageview.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [LevelListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LevelListDrawable.html) for that. In XML you can define it with a [`<level-list>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LevelList) tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<level-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/scratch"
        android:maxLevel="0" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/tea"
        android:maxLevel="1" />
</level-list>
```

You can then control the level by calling `setLevel()` for the drawable or `setImageLevel()` for the `ImageButton` that is displaying the drawable. You would do this from the click listener for the flip button.

Comment: I tried your solution but some how its not working for me. Can you please suggest some more idea in this.

Comment: @Scorpion - I don't know what you tried or what didn't work about it. Can you edit your post and provide these details?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's too late maybe not, but just to notify that I've developed a new library [FlipView](https://github.com/davideas/FlipView) that includes basic flip animation and extends `ViewFlipper`. I mean a fully customizable library where you will be able to swap any kind of views and layouts with any kind of animation and shapes you desire (and much more), included the Gmail image flipping.

Please have a look.